# Overlapping Polygons

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api, heat-map, overlapping-features

[image: Overlapping Polygons]

I have a project that requires us to plot floods in a certain area, the example below shows the flood areas.  What I would like to know is how would I be able to shows these polygons in a better fashion.  What I want is to show in a way wherein the overlapped area of the polygons are shown in a darker shade of blue; since i need to be able to show the area where it usually floods.  Any suggestions? BTW these areas are all drawn using google.maps.polygon wherein the coordinates came from the database.  It is also suggested that we use heatmaps, do you guys know of any way I can turn these polygons into heatmaps format.